# `document.querySelector('game-canvas')` is `null`

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game in JavaScript, by following a tutorial, but the browser console says *“Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read property '`getContext`' of `null`”*.

Here is my script:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('game-canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Cannot read property 'getContext' of Null, but <script> is after <canvas> and IDs match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324878/javascript-cannot-read-property-getcontext-of-null-but-script-is-after-can)

Comment: `document.querySelector('game-canvas')` implies that you have a `<game-canvas>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is null because the querySelector method cannot find "game-canvas" in the DOM. You have to define if it's a class or an id.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: This is the typo error.

Answer (score 0):

If your canvas element has an id attribute with the value game-canvas, you need to specify #game-canvas as argument to querySelector.